# Objective-C - image.size.width works but [[image size] width] doesn't. Message notation for struct CGSize?

Tags: objective-c

Objective-C -  image.size.width works but [[image size] width] doesn't. Message notation for struct CGSize?

I'm a big fan of classic message notation in Objective-C, don't know why but it just clicks.

image.size.width works and returns and int, however [[image size] width] doesn't

I understand why it doesn't, [image size] returns a CGSize struct which is C, and message notation doesn't work there. However using image.size.width just masks everything and it seems everything is like C, which it isn't.

How would message notation combine with this to keep both Objective and C expressiveness?

Comment: `image.size` is send `size` message to image. image is objective-c object. size.width is access a variable in struct CGSize.

Comment: That's what I said above... now how you use both message notation and that . struct in one line?

Comment: The compiler just supports it. It is a short way of writing `CGSize size = image.size;size.width...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[image size]` return `CGSize`. `CGSize` is C's struct.
You can use `[]` only for objective-c.
`.width` isn't message in that case, it's direct access to member of struct.

So you can write only: `[image size].width` if you opponent of convenient dot-notation.

Comment: Perfect! I looks weird. I like it.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to you the use of NSStringFromCGSize

```
NSLog(NSStringFromCGSize(image.size));
```